# Android studio image saving to external storage

Tags: android, kotlin, android-external-storage

So I've created a function to save photos to gallery with the name of the application, everything was working just fine, I worked on other stuff in the app (which are not related to this function) then when I wanted to use this function again it stopped working, here is my code

```
 fun saveImage(itemImage: View, activity: Activity) {
    var fileName: String
    val imageFromView = getBitmapFromView(itemImage)

    ByteArrayOutputStream().apply {
        Bitmap.createBitmap(imageFromView).compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, this)
        fileName = UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(this.toByteArray()).toString().replace("-", "")
    }

    val imageFile = File("${Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().absolutePath}/ChatOut/$fileName.jpg/")
    val direct = File("${Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().absolutePath}/ChatOut/").apply {
        if (!exists())
            mkdirs()
    }

    if (!imageFile.exists()) {
        File(direct, "$fileName.jpg").apply {
            FileOutputStream(this).apply {
                Bitmap.createBitmap(imageFromView).compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, this)
                flush()
                close()
            }
        }.let {
            activity.contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    ContentValues().apply {
                        put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis())
                        put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg")
                        put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, it.absolutePath)
                    }
            )
       }

       Toast.makeText(activity, "saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    } else
       Toast.makeText(activity, "Already saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

this function checks if an image is already saved or not, if not then it saves it, I am getting a

```
/storage/emulated/0/ChatOut/0fe4706621ce318fb4e7292e16bcfb17.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

I have usage permission in my manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I made sure that the permission is granted as well.

for some reason no matter what I do the mkdirs() returns false, it never succeeds in creating the file or the directory...

Please help, and thank you for your time.

Comment: AFAIK, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() will not work (it will return null) at Android Q or above, maybe your device OS has been upgrated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved my problem by applying the following code, in case someone else is having the same problem

```
fun saveImage(itemImage: View, activity: Activity) {
    val fileName: String
    val imageFromView = getBitmapFromView(itemImage)

    ByteArrayOutputStream().apply {
        imageFromView.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, this)
        fileName = UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(this.toByteArray()).toString().replace("-", "")
    }

    val imageFile =  File("${activity.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)}/ChatOut/$fileName.jpg/")

    if (!imageFile.exists()) {

        val contentResolver = ContentValues().apply {
            put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis())
            put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg")
            put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, imageFile.absolutePath)
        }

         activity.contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentResolver).apply {
              imageFromView.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, activity.contentResolver.openOutputStream(this!!))
         }


        Toast.makeText(activity, "saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
     } else
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Already saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}



fun getBitmapFromView(view: View): Bitmap {
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(view.width, view.height,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888).apply {
        Canvas(this).apply {
            view.draw(this)
        }
    }
}
```